# Typescript declare an optional method on super prototype

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class Test {
    value: any;

    getSomething() {
       // doSomething doesn't exist on type Test
        if (typeof this.doSomething === 'function') {
            return this.doSomething(this.value);
      }
  }
}

class A extends Test {
    doSomething(value) {
      console.log(value);
    }
}

const a = new A();

a.getSomething();
```

I want the `doSomething` method to be optional. If sub classes want to implement it, they could, but they don't have to. How can I declare it in the super class as undefined and prevent the ts error?

Comment: How about defining `doSomething() {} ` in super, so you wouldn't even need the `typeof this.doSomething === 'function'` check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the method as optional on the `Test` class

```
class Test {
    value: any;
    doSomething?(p: any): any;
    getSomething() {
       // doSomething doesn't exist on type Test
        if (typeof this.doSomething === 'function') {
            return this.doSomething(this.value);
      }
  }
}

class A extends Test {
    doSomething(value) {
      console.log(value);
    }
}

const a = new A();
a.getSomething();
```

**Personal Note:** you learn something new each day, had no idea it was possible, but I thought to myself what would be the syntax if this existed, and lo and behold it worked .